# Calculate the tangent unit vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the tangent unit vectors  $$\overrightarrow T (t)$$ , normal unitary $$\overrightarrow N (t)$$ and binormal $$ \overrightarrow B (t)$$ for the next vectorial function

$$\overrightarrow r (t) =〈e^{-t} ,\sqrt{2t},e^t>$$

I tried, but apparently I have some I think I'm confusing scalar with vector.I asked my teacher, but he is new and his explanation was not entirely good. If you can help me I will thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- $T(t)$ is classically the normalized speed vector $(-e^{-t},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2t}},e^t)$ ("normalized" means divided by its norm).
- $N(t)$ is the derivative of $T(t)$, normalized afterwards,
- $B(t)$ is the cross product $T(t) \times N(t).$